# Ruling span derivation?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I have recently read a paper about the ruling span for electrical wires and they have an approximation that looks like it can be derived with mathematical intuition only. I'd like to find a derivation of this equality..

$$
S_R=\frac{\sqrt{S_1^3+S_2^3+...+S_n^3}}{\sqrt{S_1+S_2+...+S_n}}=S_{ave}+\frac{2}{3}(S_{max}-S_{ave})
$$

Update: This approximation might be geometrically motivated, I'm not entirely sure. Here is an excerpt of the definition:

The ruling span, for any series of non-uniform spans between dead ends, (S1, S2, S3 - Sn feet) is a calculated
span length for which the conductor tension best represents the average tension in the conductor in the actual
line.

Also, there are constraints: $S_{max}\leq\frac{3}{2}S_{ave}$ and $S_{max}\leq\frac{5}{4}S_{R}$, where $S_R$ is the ruling span in the above main equation.

Comment: Is there any assumption on the $S_i$'s?  Let $s:=S_\text{avg}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nS_i$ and $m:=S_\text{max}=\max\left\{S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_n\right\}$.  From what I see, the only assumptions we need are $S_i\geq 0$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, and $s\leq m\leq ns$.    Unfortunately, the value of $E:=\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n S_i^3}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n S_i}}$ can be anything from $\sqrt{\frac{(ns-m)^3}{ns(n-1)^2}+\frac{m^3}{ns}}$ to $m$.  Hence, the approximation is quite bad.

Comment: Even in the limit $m\approx s$, we only have $s+\mathcal{O}\left((m-s)^2\right) \leq E \leq s+(m-s)$.